# Adding up total through a for loop - total always 0

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I have a method to work out intervals from a file containing training data. It detects spikes and drops in power to figure out intervals and I'm developing a method to work out averages for each interval. Here is the method:

```
public void getIntervalData()
        {
            //Remove first drop anomaly
            drops.Remove(0);        
            int intervalAltitude;
            int intervalPower;
            int intervalSpeed;
            int altitudeAddUp = 0;
            int powerAddUp = 0;
            int speedAddUp = 0;   
            int counter = 0;
            //Loop through to get all spikes and drops
            for (int j = 0; j < spikes.Count(); j++)
            {                
                int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(spikes[j]);
                int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(drops[j]);
                MessageBox.Show(firstNumber.ToString());
                counter++;
                //Difference to work out averages
                int difference = secondNumber - firstNumber;       
                //Get seperate interval data (first number = spike, second number = drop)
                for (int i = firstNumber; i < secondNumber; i++)
                {                      
                    int altitudeNumber = altitudeList[i];
                    int powerNumber = powerList[i];
                    int speedNumber = Convert.ToInt32(speedList[i]);                   
                    //Add up data
                    altitudeAddUp += altitudeNumber;     
                    powerAddUp += powerNumber;
                    speedAddUp += speedNumber;                    
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Alt add up:" + altitudeAddUp.ToString());
                intervalAltitude = altitudeAddUp / difference;
                intervalPower = powerAddUp / difference;
                intervalSpeed = speedAddUp / difference;  
                intervalAverages.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(intervalAltitude, intervalPower, intervalSpeed));
                MessageBox.Show("Interval: " + counter.ToString() + ": Avgs: " + intervalAverages[0]);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Interval averages added. There were: " + counter + " intervals"); 
        }
```

altitudeAddUp, powerAddUp and speedAddUp are always 0, but I can't figure out why it's not adding up. Probably a rookie error I just can't see it.

I've used a message box previously to test if altitudeNumber, powerNumber and speedNumber contain data and they do, but it won't add up.

Comment: As they are integers, there is a chance that on this line `intervalSpeed = speedAddUp / difference; ` or another similar one you are dividing and creating a decimal which gets rounded to 0.

Comment: are you sure that `firstNumber < secondNumber`?

Comment: as the above comment suggests, if the secondNumber is < the firstNumber you'll never enter the second for loop where you are doing the incriminating

Comment: use debuger. put breakpoint. press `f10` to go step by step. you will find out

Comment: Do you have the code that instantiates `spikes`, `drops`, `altitudeList`, `powerList`, and `speedList`?

Comment: Add some Console.WriteLine() statements into code so you can see what is happening.  Then add at end of code Console.ReadLine() so the window doesn't close.   You also can write the debug info to a file.   This is an old debug method going back 40 - 50 years and still works very well.

Comment: Or just use a debugger. We don't have access to your data so we can't tell if, for example,  `firstNumber < secondNumber` or not.

Comment: @jdweng He is using `MessageBox.Show()` because this is a forms application and not a console application. Basically the *second* oldest method going back 20 years. That works well until you leave a message box in production code. **Doh!**

Comment: Well, just noticed the names: spike -> `firstNumber`, drop -> `secondNumber`. Based on names, I would expect spike > drop, which would confirm `firstNumber > secondNumber` so the increment loop is skipped (also, `difference` is negative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that all your variables are integers. And integers don't have any decimal precision, that means that if an interval is `0.999`, the actual integer value is `0` (0.999 doesn't exist as integer, to the value is truncated when you call `ToInt32`).

Use `float`, `double` or `decimal`, depending on the need of precision and range.

Comment: According to OP, problem is not with `intervalXY` but `xyAddUp` variables

Comment: The values are read from `spikes[j]`, which are done `ToInt32`. That can yield `0` too.

Comment: Exactly - unless the statement 'altitudeAddUp, powerAddUp and speedAddUp are always 0' is false, it is probably not the division issue.